# NetBeans MySQL driver connection error dist Jar file

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jar

I'm developing a program with NetBeans which connects to a MySQL online server using PHPMyadmin, running the program through NetBeans it works perfectly but when I try to run it just using the Jar file in the "dist" folder of the proyect throw me an error which I'll post it at the end.

My question is:

Why is this happening in NetBeans works but not with the dist Jar file?

How can I run it in other computer without using NetBeans just double clicking the Jar file? (I just downloaded the latest java version in another computer which has not the NetBean IDE and I got the error that could'nt connect to com jdbc mysql driver).

Thank you for your support.

Here is a error:

```
Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

Java.net.ConnectException

MESSAGE: Connection refused: connect

STACKTRACE:

Java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
At.java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)

At java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)

At java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)

At java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)

At java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (Unknown Source)

At java.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

At java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

At java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)

At java.net.Socket<init>(Unknown Source)

At com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)

At com.mysql.jdbc.MysqllO.<init>(MysqlIIO.java:271)

...
...

...
```

Comment: You are talking about `MySQL` and the version you are using is not `Embedded` I guess? Until and unless you use an [Embedded DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database) it wont work directly from `jar` or any executable source

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple test that was successful both inside and outside of Netbeans. I used a regular java (Ant) project except I added the MySQL JDBC driver as a library. (right-click Libraries icon in the project window, add library  and select it from the list.)  Add the following single file as MySqlCheck in the mysqlcheck package. Change localhost to the correct host for you, somebody to your username, mypasswd, test to some database you have and Untitled to some small table useful for testing. Since the connection url is hard-coded in this example, it might solve a problem if your getting your connection info from a command-line argument, system property or something else likely to be different inside vs outside of Netbeans.

If it builds correctly in the dist subdirectory will be your jar and in a lib subdirectory of that will be mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar. If you move the jar in dist you always need to move the lib subdirectory with its jars too. Just recursively zipping up the whole dist directory is probably the best way. If you move to a different host the localhost string needs to change to the actual host. Also the user permissions and network settings could cause a problem, that perhaps an admin would have to fix.

The project could also be cloned from here:

https://github.com/wshackle/MysqlCheck

To test open up a Terminal and enter:

java -jar dist/yourproject.jar

```
package mysqlcheck;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
* @author Will Shackleford {@literal <wshackle@gmail.com> }
 */
public class MysqlCheck {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn
                = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?"
                        + "user=somebody&password=mypasswd");
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from Untitled;");
        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
        for (int i = 0; i < meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("i = " + i);
            System.out.println("columnName=" + meta.getColumnName(i + 1));
            rs.first();
            do {
                System.out.println("colunmString=" + rs.getString(i + 1));
            } while (rs.next());
        }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // handle any errors
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle any errors
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```